# Constructive solid Geometry in functional programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, raytracing, algebraic-data-types

I'm implementing CSG in a haskell program.
When I did that in an OOP lahguage I was inspired by the Composite Patron.

I had an abstract class "Object", some concrete objects (Sphere, plane, etc), and a concrete class "CompositeObject" whith an operator and two pointers to Object.

To implement the CSG tree in that way in Haskell I was thinking in a recursive datatype:

```
data Shape = Sphere (..some types here..)
           | ..other primitive objects..
           | Composite Shape Op Shape
```

Then I define the functions over objects by pattern matching.
The problem here, is that all objects must be in this module. All objects are concentrated in a monolith.

I think that is a good idea having a typeclass for objects:

```
class Shape a where
  intersection :: Ray   -> a -> [Points]
  normal       :: Point -> a -> Vector
  ...
```

Now I define instances for Sphere, plane, cilinder, etc.

But what about composite objects? How can I create a type constructed from two types of a class, with the class functions depending on the constructors, or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual pattern is to skip the class and just make it data, like this:

```
data Shape = Shape
    { intersection :: Ray -> [Point]
    , normal       :: Point -> Vector
    }
```

Then you would have functions like `sphere` that took a position and a radius and produced a `Shape`; or a composite object that took two `Shape`s and did something with them.